# Calorimetry: Temperature Increase due to stirring of reactants

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetics, calorimetry

I am not yet in university, but I hear a common first-year chemistry lab/practical is to do calorimetry taking into consideration the small (and usually negligible) rise in temperature due to the reaction container being stirred.

What is the standard method for estimating/calculating this increase in temperature, given the rate at which the stirring occurs and all the other necessary information? Is this possible to obtain an answer using molecular kinetics or are these calculations done solely on guesswork?

Comment: There is a difference between swirling the solution in a blender and giving it an "inconsequential" stir. Chemistry is often highly dependent on significant figures, not mathematical exactness. So yes a stir will raise the temperature, but if that stir only raises the temperature by a millionth of a degree when the reaction raises the temperature by 10 degrees, then the stir doesn't really matter.

Comment: I suppose you are referring to a modern reincarnation of one of Joule's experiments demonstrating the energy equivalence of heat and work? The idea is that if the container is well insulated, constant stirring will lead to an increase in temperature of the solution, even when reactions are absent. The computation is based on the work done by the stirrer (which should be relatively easy to determine), the heat capacity of the solution and/or the change in temperature (2 of these 3 are required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed experimentally, not through theory or computation. You run one experiment starting with the reactants, measuring the change in temperature over time. Then, you run a control with a similar solution that does not react (e.g. the product mixture), setting the mixer to the same speed. This will allow you to correct for any effect not due to the reaction. The stirring will be a minor contribution (depending on the tools used, not measurable at all). Other effects are large and always have to be corrected for (for example, if the reaction needs to be started with a spark and an ignition charge).

> What is the standard method for estimating/calculating this increase in temperature, given the rate at which the stirring occurs and all the other necessary information?

The work done to stir is based on the viscosity of the fluid. The faster you spin, the more work is necessary. In the classic experiment by Joule mentioned in the comments, a special stirring mechanism was used to have a large effect on the temperature. The experiment served to figure out the specific heat capacity of water (what energy is required to raise the temperature of a certain mass of water by a certain amount). You can read more about the experiment [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/DeVoe%27s_%22Thermodynamics_and_Chemistry%22/03%3A_The_First_Law/3.07_Shaft_Work).